# Inverse log normal distribution

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get random numbers  generated by a log normal distribution in VBA?
I used

```
    Dim upper As Double, lower As Double

    ' Declare 2 arrays 
    Dim irr(26) As Double
    Dim lirr(26) As Double

    ' set the upper and lower band
    upper = 0.125
    lower = 0.02

...
     lirr(i ) = WorksheetFunction.LogInv(Rand, (upper - lower), lower) + lower
```

However I get an error.

Comment: Please include the error and any research you have done on it. And is it log normal or inverse log normal as in the title and code?

Comment: `Rand` isn't VBA. `Rnd()` is.

Comment: As @JohnColeman says and  generally put Application.WorksheetFunction

Comment: "I get an error" - good, but not good enough. What error exactly? Which instruction? Run-time or compile-time? What's `Rand`? Please read [mcve] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Base 1
Public Function LOGINV_SAMPLE(Optional n As Integer = 1, Optional md As Variant = 1, Optional stdv As Variant = 0) As Variant
'#Execute this as array formula i.e Cnt+Shft+Enter
 Dim x(), i, p As Variant
  ReDim Preserve x(n)
  For i = 1 To n Step 1
   Randomize
    p = Rnd()
   x(i) = Application.LogNorm_Inv(p, stdv, md)
 Next i

 LOGINV_SAMPLE = Application.Transpose(x)

End Function
```

This works.